# Grounding Pin is Stuck in the Outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

The grounding pin of my extension cord broke off in the outlet when I unplugged it.

Is it safe to use pliers to pull the pin out of the outlet?

Will I get shocked?

Comment: If everything is wired correctly to modern Code, yes, even a single failure (e.g. broken wire NOT wired wrong) should protect you.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. This is a matter of personal risk tolerance and will prove to be little more than a popularity vote. If you wanted to make it more objective, revise to ask whether the ground terminal in an outlet normally carries current.

Comment: @isherwood Eh, I think this is the same question as what you said, just asked a different way. E.g. "Will I get shocked" -> "Yes, if the ground terminal is wired to carry current". or "No, if the ground terminal is wired correctly." Breaking something off inside an outlet could easily be something risk averse home owners would call a contractor/electrician for, but isn't at all necessary to do, so asking if it's generally safe to attempt themselves seems within the scope of DIY.SE.

Comment: @isherwood That being said, it's effectively a duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62936/is-it-dangerous-if-the-ground-pin-of-a-3-prong-plug-breaks-off-in-the-outlet IMHO.

Comment: Funny how many have metal lamps? Every one is required to have the ground attached to the body of the lamp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it dangerous if the ground pin of a 3 prong plug breaks off in the outlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62936/is-it-dangerous-if-the-ground-pin-of-a-3-prong-plug-breaks-off-in-the-outlet)

Comment: If you repair the cord with a new plug, consider checking the other end vigorously with pliers.  Or just replace both ends with new quality fittings.

Answer (score 15):

You'll want to turn off the breaker. You should be alright but if the internals of the outlet are damaged or broken, you don't want to come in contact with them when you pull out the ground plug. You might even want to replace the outlet since the grounding terminal shouldn't just break off under normal use, unless the extension cord was really damaged.

Comment: Enjoying both JACK and Ed,'s comments,  I agree with both of you. But when it come to newbies, I always recommend more safety measures: like turn off the breaker for the circuit and test to be sure it's off, then with insulated pliers do what needs to be done.  I'd personally have no issue pulling out a broken ground prong with the power on, but that's not what I tell my friends who ask for advice!  Take Care and Happy New Year. Looking forward to 2020 to be GONE!.

Comment: Jack I probably repair at least  20 cords a year at my mill it is almost always molded plugs that loose the pin.  For the receptacle to be damaged to the point of getting a shock from a ground is really not feasible the testing includes weighted drop tests if the receptacle can’t hold up to the standards it would not pass UL certification there would be heavy visible damage even then I doubt there would be an issue because if it was the connection would trip the breaker.

Comment: Agreed the outlet should not be suspect unless there's any other evidence to believe there's something wrong with it.  Cheap extension cords with molded plugs lose ground pins all the time - especially with hard use.  Like @EdBeal, I threw out two just last week and see a similar failure rate.

Comment: @EdBeal  I agree with you Ed and that's why I stated the OP should be alright doing it but just to be safe, turn off the breaker especially since it's a DIY'er asking the question.  I'd wager your knowledge far exceeds all  DIY'ers  and probably most of the people on this site so any advise I'd give to you would be a lot different than what I'd give to a DIY'er.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson you know the pandemic doesn't go away just because the date rolled over, right?

Comment: @user253751  Of course. But enough other crappy stuff happened in 2020 that it will be good to "turn the page".

Answer (score 9):

The ground pin is safe to remove with pliers.
The ground will normally only have power on it in a fault condition or if you have electronic switches no neutral that use the ground but even then it is safe with un insulated pliers most metal lamps and devices the metal is attached to the ground and we don’t get shocked by that.

Comment: Any electronic switch which uses ground *with UL's blessing* should be safe too, as it should inherently limit current to under 5ma in any foreseeable failure mode.

Comment: @harper there is also a limit to 5 or 6 of these devices so the actual limit may be less than 5 ma but I have not looked into that limit and don’t remember if it is per branch circuit or total.

Comment: Really hoping that future Google visitors to this page aren't mistaken about which one's the ground pin

Comment: Should be, yes. You never know how stupidly your house is wired though. Look up "reverse polarity bootleg ground" which is where someone wired the live wire to the ground pin...

Comment: As a professional I disagree if the pin was live that would be a direct short to ground and it would be no different than a metal lamp connected to the circuit where the frame is connected to ground so it “should be safe”.

Comment: @sneftel I believe most do know what the grounding pin is but even some electricians do not understand the difference between grounding and grounded. Grounding is the green or bare wire attached to a grounding electrode system. Grounded is the utility or separately derived neutral white or gray in code speak they are required to be connected or bonded at the main panel but no place else.

Comment: @EdBeal If the pin was live it would mean the ground screw on the socket is wired to a live wire instead of a ground wire. The pin would not be a direct short to ground, it would be a direct short to live.

Comment: @User253751 we can come up with all kinds of stupid , read the question again and guess again.

Comment: @EdBeal "reverse polarity bootleg ground" is a real thing that real people have found in their real houses, not something hypothetical. Of course, it's *unlikely*, but you never know...

Comment: @user253751 a bootleg ground is not reverse polarity it is combining the neutral and the grounding points at any place other than the main panel. Can you touch your main panel safely because they are the same there and both are connected by code. Objectionable current was not even a thing until the 99 code that’s when neutrals and grounds were isolated the homes built prior to that time still have the same wiring for the vast majority and they are still safe as defined by code.

Comment: @EdBeal a "reverse polarity bootleg ground" is a bootleg ground which is also reverse polarity. Two "common" wiring mistakes combined together. Why didn't you Google it?

Comment: @user253751 I have been fixing “stupid” for 4 decades I don’t think google is going to be able to teach me anything I haven’t seen having been a licensed general journeyman in multiple states. What state are you licensed in or are you an internet only electrician?

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the breaker for that outlet, it's the only way to be sure you're safe. If you don't know which breaker controls that outlet then plug in a lamp, turn it on, and go hunting for the breaker. As far as I know lamps commonly use only 2 prongs so the ground pin should not be an issue.

If you can then remove the prong with pliers and turn the breaker back on.

After doing so test the receptacle with a receptacle tester like this:

[image: Klein Tools receptacle tester: model RT210]

It will tell you if the broken prong has caused any immediately obvious issues.

If you fear hidden damage that might not make itself known until a future date then it's fairly simple and cheap to replace the outlet. Once again, turn off the breaker before attempting this.

Pro-tip: take picture of both sides of the outlet before replacing it. I have seen far too many posts on this site where someone disconnects a rat nest of wires in an outlet or switch and then asks the community which wire goes where.